# PDF Adobe Sign Automation

Tags: excel, pdf, automation, adobe

So I've been researching how to solve a repetitive task I have for work.

Basically the flow is this:

I have 50-60 timesheets every pay (2x month) period, for each employee.
I currently use Adobe Sign to get the employee and their supervisor's signature. Sent to each one, with the fields dragged and dropped onto the document.

I wanted to know if there are any specific technologies out there that I could use to automate this workflow?

I thought of utilizing a list of employee emails along with their manager's and find a way to leverage it, but I can't figure out how to go about it or where to start.

Comment: Welcome to stack**overflow**. `technologies out there` What (computer programming) tools are you comfortable with? You tagged (MS) Excel - what is the input (appearing how), what is the desired effect?